# Ungroup diff's output

Tags: diff

I've got two files, and output of `diff` looks like this:

```
33428,33429c33428,33429
< lucid-security|main|icedtea-6-jre-cacao|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
< lucid-security|main|icedtea6-plugin|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
---
> lucid-security|main|icedtea-6-jre-cacao|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|main|icedtea6-plugin|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
33835,33842c33835,33842
< lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-dbg|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
< lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-demo|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
< lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-doc|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
< lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-jdk|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
< lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-jre|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
< lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-jre-headless|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
< lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-jre-lib|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
< lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-source|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
---
> lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-dbg|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-demo|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-doc|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-jdk|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-jre|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-jre-headless|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-jre-lib|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-source|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
34182c34182
< lucid-security|universe|openjdk-6-jre-zero|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
---
> lucid-security|universe|openjdk-6-jre-zero|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
```

I would like to "ungroup" the output, so the old line is followed by the new line. Could be looking like this:

```
< lucid-security|main|icedtea-6-jre-cacao|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|main|icedtea-6-jre-cacao|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
< lucid-security|main|icedtea6-plugin|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|main|icedtea6-plugin|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
< lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-dbg|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-dbg|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
< lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-demo|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-demo|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
< lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-doc|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-doc|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
< lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-jdk|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-jdk|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
< lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-jre|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-jre|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
< lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-jre-headless|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-jre-headless|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
< lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-jre-lib|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-jre-lib|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
< lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-source|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|main|openjdk-6-source|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
< lucid-security|universe|openjdk-6-jre-zero|6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
> lucid-security|universe|openjdk-6-jre-zero|6b20-1.9.4-0ubuntu1~10.04.1
```

I don't need the information about position of changed lines, and I don't even care about lines added or deleted in second file. Just this quick compare of changes.

Answer (score 1):

A quick regex can nicely sort out which lines are prefixed by a given character.

```
diff file1 file2 | egrep '^[<>]' > output.txt
```

That should leave you with just positive and negative changes, no line numbers, no separators.

Comment: That will, in fact, not diff line by line, so you will still have to catch some blocks by eye. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138749/diffing-without-grouping-unrelated-blocks indicates this cannot be solved with the standard diff utility.

Comment: You can remove the numbers and separations this way: diff --changed-group-format="%>%<" --unchanged-group-format="" file_1 file_2.

Comment: But thank you for pointing me way how to solve my problem. By parameters above I removed also the leading ">" and "<" and then sorted the result with `sort`. Not general solution, but works in this case.